# R: how to do colMeans on a List of matrix

Tags: r

I would like to know how to do colMeans on a List of matrix.

Please show to how to do this in R.

Thanks a lot.

Here is my dataset looks like:

```
> dataset
     [,1]     [,2]    
[1,] 22.04031 28.03182
[2,] 23.94481 28.17275
[3,] 16.39071 25.44523
[4,] 22.10198 22.45534
[5,] 24.95194 27.95778
[6,] 33.09007 36.74856
```

My desired result after colMeans will be do the mean on both col [,1] and [,2]. The mean for these two columns will be 23.75330 and 28.13524, respectively.

Here is other information about this dataset:

```
> str(dataset)
List of 12
 $ : num 22
 $ : num 23.9
 $ : num 16.4
 $ : num 22.1
 $ : num 25
 $ : num 33.1
 $ : num 28
 $ : num 28.2
 $ : num 25.4
 $ : num 22.5
 $ : num 28
 $ : num 36.7
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 6 2
```

Melting down the dataset. The column value is what I want for colMeans.

```
> melt(dataset)
   Var1 Var2    value       NA
1     1    1 22.04031 28.03182
2     2    1 23.94481 28.17275
3     3    1 16.39071 25.44523
4     4    1 22.10198 22.45534
5     5    1 24.95194 27.95778
6     6    1 33.09007 36.74856
7     1    2 22.04031 28.03182
8     2    2 23.94481 28.17275
9     3    2 16.39071 25.44523
10    4    2 22.10198 22.45534
11    5    2 24.95194 27.95778
12    6    2 33.09007 36.74856
```

Comment: does `sapply(myList, colSums)` do what you want?

Comment: nope.. it shows: 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions.

Comment: Please print out your desired output in your question. You say "he column value is what I want for colMeans," but then say you want "an array of at least two dimensions." This is confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your list has a `dim` attribute, you can just use:

```
mat <- array(unlist(dataset), dim = dim(dataset))
colMeans(mat)
```

Edit: Thanks, @RichardScriven, for the improvement.

Comment: You could even shorten it to `matrix(unlist(dataset), dim(dataset))` since the first value of `dim` is `nrow` and the second will be dropped.

Comment: Good to know I need to unlist the dataset first. It worked just use this: 'colMeans(matrix(unlist(dataset), ncol = 2))'

Comment: @RichardScriven Thanks! I also changed the function to `array` to account for more than two dimensions.

Comment: @Kuo-HsienChang Correct, although I wouldn't recommend hardcoding the `2` here and just use `dim(dataset)`. Anyway, if this answers your question, then please press the check mark next to the answer to close the thread.